# jsf 2.0 viewscope in two windows need to refresh each other

Tags: ajax, jsf, view-scope, browser-tab, property-injection

I have a problem:

I have a View-Scoped bean/view with an overview of some data (list). when someone clicks on an item, it opens another view-scoped window/browser tab which loads and shows some detailed information about the item clicked.

All I need is the "overview-window" to change the status-image from "unread" to "read" (i would prefer ajax), when the user opens a detail page, so i need a kind of a property-injection; but does this work in two different view-scopes?

How can I do this?

thanks very much for your help

**add. info: I tried property-injection (other view-scoped bean); but the values are resetted; seems like it created a new view-scoped overview bean with no content)**

Comment: Do you really need to store it on the fly instead of your own server? Data like read-unread looks for a single *row* looks like an entity status that must go on database. This looks like an application data design issue more than a JSF problem.

Comment: Yep, you are right; as soon as the user opens the detail page, the database gets updated. so i also want to update the "overview" page automaticaly if the user does not reload it.

Comment: Look at pushing/polling.

Comment: like primefaces-push?
or something else? do you have a short sample code?